# Настройка pagination для отображения списка страниц

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, spring, intellij-idea

Всем привет!
Начал понемногу изучать визуальную часть веба и столкнулся с проблемой. Хочу настроить отображение существующих страниц, но при просмотре страниц находящихся по краям списка происходит неприятное (см. изображения), всего 76 страниц.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно изменить цикл или условие внутри него.

Имеется следующий код:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation" th:unless="${studentListing.totalPages == 0}">

                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li th:if="${studentListing.number == 0}" class="active">
                        <a th:text="1"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:unless="${studentListing.number == 0}">
                        <a th:if="${studentCriteria==null}" th:href="@{/(page=0, size=20)}"
                           th:text="1"></a>
                        <a th:unless="${studentCriteria==null}" th:href="@{/(page=0, size=20, lastName=${studentCriteria.lastName},
                    firstName=${studentCriteria.firstName}, middleName=${studentCriteria.middleName}, fromBirthDate=${studentCriteria.fromBirthDate},
                    toBirthDate=${studentCriteria.toBirthDate}, gender=${studentCriteria.gender}, isActive=${studentCriteria.isActive})}"
                           th:text="Начало"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="pagination" th:each="newPage: ${#numbers.sequence(studentListing.number - 3, studentListing.number + 3)}">
                    <li th:if="${newPage == studentListing.number}" class="active">
                        <a th:text="${newPage + 1}"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:unless="${newPage == studentListing.number}">
                        <a th:if="${studentCriteria==null}" th:href="@{/(page=${newPage}, size=20)}"
                           th:text="${newPage + 1}"></a>
                        <a th:unless="${studentCriteria==null}" th:href="@{/(page=${newPage}, size=20, lastName=${studentCriteria.lastName},
                    firstName=${studentCriteria.firstName}, middleName=${studentCriteria.middleName}, fromBirthDate=${studentCriteria.fromBirthDate},
                    toBirthDate=${studentCriteria.toBirthDate}, gender=${studentCriteria.gender}, isActive=${studentCriteria.isActive})}"
                           th:text="${newPage + 1}"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li th:if="${studentListing.number == studentListing.totalPages}" class="active">
                        <a th:text="${studentListing.totalPages}"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li th:unless="${studentListing.number == studentListing.totalPages}">
                        <a th:if="${studentCriteria==null}" th:href="@{/(page=${studentListing.totalPages}, size=20)}"
                           th:text="${studentListing.totalPages}"></a>
                        <a th:unless="${studentCriteria==null}" th:href="@{/(page=${studentListing.totalPages - 1}, size=20, lastName=${studentCriteria.lastName},
                    firstName=${studentCriteria.firstName}, middleName=${studentCriteria.middleName}, fromBirthDate=${studentCriteria.fromBirthDate},
                    toBirthDate=${studentCriteria.toBirthDate}, gender=${studentCriteria.gender}, isActive=${studentCriteria.isActive})}"
                           th:text="${studentListing.totalPages}"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привели пример кода где всплывающая цыфра калькулируется перед попаданием на страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена, извините что не отметил сразу, отмечал.
Создал цикл который добавляет все существующие страницы и условие которое пропускает только определённые страницы, вроде нормально работает.